# Select Distinct Array Values from Postgresql Table

Tags: postgresql, distinct, distinct-values

I have a PostgreSQL database table which looks like this

```
content
title          category              content
Hello World    ["Great"]             This is the content
Learn More     ["Learn", "Great"]    Learn about things
```

I know this is not the best way to store data like that, but it can't be changed at this point.

I want to get an array of unique categories in one query, some thing like this:

`SELECT DISTINCT category FROM content`

And end up with an array like this:

`["Great", "Learn"]`

I know it would be easy if the categories were in a separate table, but how would you do it if they are nested like this?

`category` is JSONB formatted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use array functions like;

```
select distinct unnest(category) as nestCategory from content
```

[PostgreSQL Array Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html)